# PHP Retrieve Value from Nested JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I'm working with the following JSON Object:

```
    {
  "body": {
    "subject": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", 
    "to": [
      {
        "location": "Hawthorne, CA", 
        "name": "Jeff Daniels", 
        "phoneNumber": "+15552123456", 
        "target": true
      }
    ], 
    "type": "SMS"
  }, 
  "uuid": "5797377010673708914"
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve certain values and can't work out the syntax to get the to phoneNumber value. Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
$webhook= json_decode( $webhookJSON, TRUE );
$subject = $webhook['body']['subject'];
$toPhoneNumber = $webhook['body']['to']['phoneNumber'];
```

I'm getting the `$subject` but not the `$toPhoneNumber`. I've tried adding `[0]` in a few places to get the first member of the array but this isn't working either and at this stage I'm stumped as to how I can get the to phoneNumber value from the nested array.

Comment: Just by looking at the structure: try `$webhook['body']['to'][0]['phoneNumber'];`. (`to` contains an array element, so you would need to select the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the correct way with adding `[0]` to it. I highly suggest, that you should use `print_r()` to double check the structure of the array, if your are unsure.
It would give you this:

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [subject] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            [to] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [location] => Hawthorne, CA
                            [name] => Jeff Daniels
                            [phoneNumber] => +15552123456
                            [target] => 1
                        )

                )

            [type] => SMS
        )

    [uuid] => 5797377010673708914
)
```

As you can see, you can acces the phonenumber via

```
$toPhoneNumber = $webhhok['body']['to'][0]['phoneNumber'];
```

The reason is, that you start an array within the json, everytime you use `[]`. That's why you need to use an index to access the element.

When you are in charge of the json, I would recommend to remove the array, because you don't need it there, unless you want to have multiple receipients:

```
{
  "body": {
    "subject": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "to": {
      "location": "Hawthorne, CA",
      "name": "Jeff Daniels",
      "phoneNumber": "+15552123456",
      "target": true
    },
    "type": "SMS"
  },
  "uuid": "5797377010673708914"
}
```